Number of symmetric matrices in a box of bounded determinant
Let $B$ and $T$ be positive real numbers. I'm interested in the following problem, which is about counting $2\times2$ symmetric matrices with bounded determinant and entries lying in a box:
Problem: Give an asymptotic formula for the quantity
$$\#\big\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \cap [-B,B]^3 : |ac - b^2| < T \big\}$$
where the dependence of the main term and error term on $B$ and $T$ is explicit. How big can we take $T$ without letting the error term dominate the main term?
What I know: I am aware of results due to various authors (e.g., Duke-Rudnick-Sarnak, Eskin-McMullen, and others) using various methods that give asymptotics for the quantity
$$\#\big\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \cap [-B,B]^3 : |ac - b^2| = k \big\}$$
where $k$ is fixed. There exists $ \delta \in (0,1)$ such that one can sum these fixed-$k$ asymptotics for $T < B^\delta$, without letting the error term dominate the main term. But I am more interested in the larger regime where $T$ can be as large as $B^{1 + \epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Are there methods available when the determinant is allowed to vary that don't work in the case of fixed determinant?
